# Does the R^n analog of a sphere, have the minimum surface area for a given volume?

Tags: spherical-geometry

The property is true for $n =3$. But is it also true for $n \gt 3$?

Is the object in $R^n$ with minimal surface area for a given volume, the higher dimensional analog of a sphere?

Comment: This is the isoperimetric inequality: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000019-QINU.60.22.27.7F

Comment: So, for equality, the subset S must be a ball in $R^n$, which is the higher homologue of a 3d sphere. Is that correct?